# Delphi 6 : Alphablending works between sub-image and main Canvas, but not between sub-images

Tags: delphi, canvas, alphablending, timage

I have a Delphi 6 application where I have an array of TBitmaps each containing an image (sub-image) that was created by making a call to FillRect() with clWhite to flood the TBitmap's Canvas with white, followed by a call toTextOut() to print some text to the Bitmap's Canvas.

I have a timer that updates the main Canvas, which belongs to a TImage component, with the contents of the array every Interval to reflect changes made to each sub-images X, Y coordinates since they are in motion.  First I use FillRect() with clWhite to flood the main Canvas with white.  To "print" the sub-images I simply iterate the array and call Alphablend() to "print" each sub-image on to the main Canvas.  Each sub-image has a Z coordinate that is used to control the level of opacity.  Sub-images with higher Z coordinates have a lower Alphablend() value to make them appear more transparent than those that are "up close".

The alpha-blending works great with each individual sub-image and those that have higher coordinates do indeed appear to be more transparent than those with lower Z coordinates.  However, I'm having a problem with sub-images that overlap in Z space.  Alpha-blending between overlapping sub-images does not appear to work.  Instead, the sub-image "behind" the overlapping sub-image is occluded by the white background belonging to the image that overlays it.  What I want is for the two sub-images to overlap properly so it looks like two text strings are written on top of each other.  Instead I see the front text string and everywhere the white background that comprises it's TBitmap's Canvas exists, wiping out the text string "behind" it.

Can anyone tell me why alpha-blending is working between each individual sub-image and the main Canvas, but not between sub-images?  I say between sub-images only in a temporal context and not as objects because they should all become part of the main Canvas as they print and I would expect alpha-blend to blend them properly, which is not happening.

It's almost as if the "white" between sub-images is not being treated the same as the "white" between a sub-image and the "white" belonging to the main Canvas.

FOLLOW-UP: In response to Andreas comment I set the PixelFormat of all sub-image TBitmap's to pf32bit.  Now alpha-blending is taking place "between" sub-images. Unfortunately, the the sub-image's white areas are not being treated as a Transparent color.  Instead the white background of the sub-image that is on top is being alpha-blended with the text belonging to the underlying sub-image creating a light gray frame around the sub-image on top as if it was smeared.  To get the effect I want I need the white background of a sub-image to be completely ignored.

Comment: I think you should give code and instructions to reproduce the problem, in as few steps as possible. Then you'll probably get a very accurate answer rather soon. Now we can only guess (e.g. "Have you tried to play with `PixelFormat`?").

Comment: Ok Andreas.  I'll go work something up.  I've updated my description of the problem since it appears that since I set the PixelFormat of all the sub-images to pf32bit, alpha-blending is taking place between sub-images.  Unfortunately, it's not treating the sub-image's white areas as Transparent so instead of the sub-image background completely occluding (wiping out) an underlying sub-image in Z space as before, it's being alpha-blended with the text of the overlayed sub-image, creating a smeared grey frame around the sub-image that is "on top".

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to show some images with Alphablending, try to use the [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/) library.
In this, you will find a component "ImgView32". With this one, you can easily show any kind of bitmaps with any position and alpbablend value. You have to use TBitmapLayer and make your drawings to them.

```
ImgView1:TImgView32;
a:array of TBitmapLayer;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var i:integer;

  begin
    ImgView1.Layers.Clear;
    SetLength (a,10);
    for i:=0 to High (a) do
      begin
        a[i]:=TBitmapLayer.Create(ImgView1.Layers);
        a[i].Location:=FloatRect(0,0,ImgView1.Width,ImgView1.Height);
        a[i].Scaled:=false;
        a[i].Bitmap.DrawMode:=dmOpaque;
        a[i].Bitmap.MasterAlpha:=255;
      end;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    ImgView1.Layers.Clear;
  end;

procedure Form1.DrawTextToLayer(Layer:TBitmapLayer;Text:string;X,Y:integer);
var I:TImage32;

begin
  I:=TImage32.Create(Form1);
  I.Width:=ImgView1.Width;
  I.Height:=ImgView1.Height;
  I.SetupBitmap;
  I.Bitmap.DrawMode:=dmBlend;
  I.Bitmap.Font.Size:=20;
  I.Bitmap.Font.Name:='Arial';
  I.Bitmap.Font.Style:=[fsBold];
  I.Bitmap.RenderText(x,Y,Text,2,clBlack32);
  Layer.Bitmap.Assign(I.Bitmap);
  I.Free        
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     DrawTextToLayer(a[0],'Testing 1',10,10);
     DrawTextToLayer(a[1],'Testing 2',20,20);
     a[0].Bitmap.MasterAlpha:=255;
     a[1].Bitmap.MasterAlpha:=100;
   end;
```